# Which input schemes are shown in Text Entry?

Tags: 13.10, input-language

Text Entry doesn't show all the schemes installed in /usr/share/m17n/

[image: Photo of my /usr/share/m17n/]

for example, I have sa-harvard-kyoto input. But that is not shown in Text Entry options. Does Text Entry have a different folder for languages shown? If yes, what is it?

OS: Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the solution. Actually, we can set which languages to be shown in Text Entry options. [image]

This is the Language and Support window found under System Settings.

In the options of keyboard input method system, at the bottom, change it from Default to IBus. All the input schemes shown in /usr/share/m17n/ will be present as options in Text Entry.